# How to solve this transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease issue?

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, ioexception

I'm trying to generate a signed apk of an app that is already in version code number 22, in this release I added push notifications from Firebase, so I've to add Google Services. In debug my app runs correctly, but when I try to generate the signed apk I receive the warning message above:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException:
Can't write [C:\Users\Alejandro\HCT\Project\Project-Android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar]
(Can't read [C:\Users\Alejandro\.android\build-cache\04825c1d096bb9aba606e23c0e99208109f6122a\output\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
(Duplicate zip entry [com/google/android/gms/internal/d.class ==
classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/internal/zzab.class]))
```

And this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

This is my app.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hct.btracker"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.3.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            //shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.8.0@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.8'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-login-android:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this my project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have this rules also:

```
-keep public class com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn com.github.mikephil.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue? I just don't know what is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try to clear and rebuild the project ? also to invalidate cache and restart ?

Comment: Sure, I tried @OussemaAroua and it didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.6'
    exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
}
```